# how to resolve Error when loading database in MariaDB in MAC terminal?

Tags: macos, xampp, mariadb

I am trying to use XAMPP in my mac SOURCE database which I stored in my mac desktop. When I connect the xampp and open the terminal and try to use the SOURCE command i have following screen with an error massage........

Linux debian 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-3 (2021-07-18) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Aug  4 02:29:53 2021 from 192.168.64.1

```
root@debian:~# mysql -u root
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 38
Server version: 10.4.20-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> USE dhtest
Database changed
MariaDB [dhtest]> SOURCE /Users/kamrulhasan/Desktop/Database/dh.sql;
ERROR: Failed to open file '/Users/kamrulhasan/Desktop/Database/dh.sql', error: 2
MariaDB [dhtest]>
```

Comment: `perror 2` -> "OS error code   2:  No such file or directory"

Comment: @danblack That's the issue!! Actually the 'dh.sql' file is there and I got this path by dragging the file into the terminal. That's the difficult thing for me as a novice to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: i wonder if it's because of the cross OS compatibility or lack there of. I am dealing with a dump file that was produced on Linux but I am trying to load it on OSX and it's giving me this "failed to open file" "error: 2"